# How to simulate velocity in a falling sand game?

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science

I'm creating a falling sand game and would like to implement velocity so elements can travel in different directions at varying speeds. Games such as Noita use this and it smoothens out the movement of the elements.

I have a 2d array and shift the elements around the 2d array to move them.

I've looked around and I can't find anything on this. I've gotten so far using line calculations but I'm curious as to the best method of handling this.

Another thing to consider is that if the velocity is small I still want to slowly move the elements. However if the velocity is 0.01 then it will always round down to zero and never move the element to another position.

My elements are stored in a 2d array so the calculated positions must always be integers.

**Array**

```
Element[] elements = new Element[1000][1000];
```

**Element**

```
class Element {
    // Array position
    int x, y; 

    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();

    public Element(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I implement velocity in a falling sand game?

Comment: use floats or fixed point for your positions, not integers

Comment: How are you with differential algebra?

Comment: In order to get help with your environment and `0.01` velocity, you will have to explain how you implement your environment. To get smooth changes, you can resist changes to speed and/or velocity using momentum. I have only seen it being used in Adam optimizer in AI but I'm sure it has physics basis. I'm not that familiar with physics so I have explained it the way I know how. I'm sure you can find the physics explanation If you search a bit.

Comment: @Raildex It's a 2d array of elements so the resulting positions must be integers. E.g. Element[][]. This is needed so I can make quick calculations for checking what the surrounding elements etc are.

Comment: I've added a general structure to my question.

Comment: Algorithms are language independent.  So, you forgot to tag some languages:  Python, C#, Fortran, Basic, Lisp, and Algol.  So don't spam languages.  You really don't want to combine Java with C++.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the velocity as floats, and keep the *actual* positions as floats as well:

```
class Element {
    // Array position
    int x, y; 
    
    // actual position
    float fx, fy;
    
    // velocity
    float vx, vy;
    
    public Element(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public void setVelocity(float vx, float vy) {
        this.vx = vx;
        this.vy = vy;
    }
    
    public void move() {
        // apply velocity
        this.fx += this.vx;
        this.fy += this.vy;
        
        // place position in integer matrix
        this.x = (int) fx;
        this.y = (int) fy;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Element e = new Element(10, 10);
        e.setVelocity(0.1f, 0.2f);
      
        for (int step =0; step < 100; step++) {
            e.move();    
            System.out.println(String.format("Step: %d x: %d y: %d", step, e.x, e.y));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a sand game myself. I think we can just create a new `element` type `particle` (besides `sand` and `water`) which can have velocity and direction.

`sand` can turn into a `particle` when certain conditions are met, for example, when it got blew by wind or spashed by other entities. `particles` will travel in the grid using its own logic. Again, when certain conditions are met, such as hitting something, the `particle` turns back to `sand`.

Let me know how it works out!